SwiperJS "slideFullyVisibleClass" not working with sliders in tabs
I have 3 tabs, each with different swiper in them. I'm using the slideFullyVisibleClass from SwiperJs to change the opacity styling of slides that aren't fully visible (in the viewport).
It works good on the slider that is showing in the active tab when the page loads. But when I switch tabs, the "fully visible" attribute isn't being added to fully visible slides. I assume this is because they're not read as visible in the viewport initially.
When I change breakpoints, the fully visible class gets added to slides that were previously faded out (see video). https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AIgNA94e_kJxwJ8_FAfs3GzwRFTC2L8q/view?usp=sharing
Is there any workaround for this?
I tried creating three separate CSS classes for the "visible" state, but that did not work.
